# dijit.Fieldset is undefined

Tags: javascript, dojo, fieldset

I'm trying to use a dijit.Fieldset but it's not working.  In my required array I've included "dijit/Fieldset" and in the function definition I've mapped it to Fieldset.  Other things I've included such as "dijit/form/Button" and "dojo/on" are working fine.  However, when I then try and create a Fieldset with this:

```
var temp = new Fieldset({ title: "Locations", content: "Blah" });
```

I get the message:

> Object doesn't support this action.

I enter dubug mode and can see the value of Fieldset is simply an int value of 3 (which I really don't understand).  If I instead try to access is using dijit.Fieldset I get the same error.  Then when I debug and mouse over Fieldset I get the value of undefined.  dijit is defined and gives me what you would expect when moused over.  So, I don't seem to be loading dijit.Fieldset.  Can anyone advise?  I'm using 1.9.

Thanks

**Update**

Thanks both for you help so far.  I confess I omited the full code as its a bit long winded and didn't want to put people off answering!  Here is the code - another confession, I'm not sure if this is refered to as a class or a module in dojo nomenclature.

```
define([
"dojo/_base/declare",
"dojo/_base/lang",
"dojo/dom-construct",
"dojo/on",
"dojo/html",
"dijit/registry",
"dijit/Fieldset",
"dijit/Tooltip",
"dijit/TooltipDialog",
"dijit/form/DropDownButton", 
"dgrid/OnDemandGrid",
"dgrid/Selection",
"dgrid/Keyboard",
"dgrid/extensions/DijitRegistry",
"esri/map",
"esri/tasks/route",
"esri/toolbars/edit",
"dijit/Menu",
"dijit/MenuItem",
"dijit/form/Button",
"my/app/RouteSymbols"
], function (declare, lang, domConstruct, on, html, registry, Fieldset, Tooltip) {
    return declare("my.app.RouteUtils", null, {

}
```

I also thought it looked like an error in the definition.  The odd thing is that the modules required either site (dijit/registry and dijit/Tooltip) are both loaded correctly and working properly on the page.

Regarding version, I'm using IE9.

Again, thanks.
Simon

Comment: Can you post your complete `require()`? I suppose there is a mismapping somewhere.

Comment: I've edited it to include the code, thanks.

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong with that. Are you sure you're using Dojo 1.9? Fieldset is only introduced since 1.9. Can you put this small code right behind the place where you create a `Fieldset` object? `console.log(JSON.stringify(dojo.version));`

Answer (score 0):

If the value of a module is the literal value `3`, that is because 1. you are using a built version of the toolkit, and 2. the loader has identified the module as not being an AMD module, i.e. it did not ever call the `define` function even though the script itself was loaded.

As to why this is happening with `dijit/Fieldset` specifically, without seeing exactly what you are doing or what browser you are using (the error message says IE, but it’s impossible to know what version), it’s impossible to say.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I've added extra details to explain further.